# Что есть "Цикл для контейнера"?

Tags: c++, vector

В задаче написано с помощью "Цикла для контейнера" заполнить контейнер единицами.
Возник вопрос, что это такое? (Как оказалось, это не цикл for)

Comment: Скорее всего речь о `std::for_each`, но с его помощью обычно что-то делают с уже существующими в контейнере значениями. Вставка в контейнер новых элементов не имеет ничего общего с циклом по содержимому контейнера. В таких случаях лучше привести **весь** текст задания.

Answer (score 2):

Если говорится о заполнении, то он уже имеет размер, поэтому:

```
std::vector<int> list(20);
// 20 единиц
list.assign(20, 1);
```

Метод практически проходит по каждому элементу и выполняет присваивание, но понятие "цикл контейнера" придуманное.

Варант:

```
std::list<int> list(20, 1);
```

Создает сразу  такой список: это конечно эффективней

Но  под названием "цикл для контейнера ",  подходит:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator first = list.begin(); first != list.end(); ++first)
    *first = 1;
```

Или скорее вам нужно это:

```
for (int &elem : list){
    static int i = 0;
    elem = ++i;
}
```

Заполнили возрастающими значениями, начиная от `1`

Comment: А как можно заполнить контейнер возрастающими значениями используя такой цикл `for`?:
`for (int &elem : a){elem=1;}`

Comment: а как они должны расти, так и заполняйте

Comment: Пытался так, но заполняется нулями: `for (int &elem : a) { int i = 0; elem = i; i++; }`
UPD: разобрался!

Comment: Я дописал, можете смотреть

Answer (score 0):

### Можно применить `std::generate`

С этой конструкцией вы можете описать довольно много разных вариантов заполнения:

Заполнить массив единицами:

```
std::generate(std::begin(mas), std::end(mas),
              [](){ return 1; }
              );
```

Заполнить массив возрастающими значениями, начиная с -4:

```
int initial = -4;
std::generate(std::begin(mas), std::end(mas),
              [&initial](){ return initial++; }
              );
```

Заполнить массив возрастающими значениями, начиная с -10, с шагом 3:

```
int initial = -10;
std::generate(std::begin(mas), std::end(mas),
              [&initial](){ initial += 3; return initial - 3; }
              );
```

Подробнее можно почитать на cppreference : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate .

Также обратите внимание на методы [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) и [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), ниже в комментариях AR Hovsepyan про них упомянул. Если возможно - лучше использовать их, это правильнее, несмотря на то, что [std::generate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) более универсален.

Comment: Если обратиться к стандартным альгоритмам, то `std::for_each` самый **плохой выбор** в данном случаи, поскольку есть более специализированные альгоритмы, такие как   `std::fill`  для первого случая,   `std::iota`  для второго, и  `std::generate` для третьего...

Comment: std::generate отличный выбор, не знал про него, он тут как универсальный вариант годится. Я заменю в ответе на него все примеры, так будет правильнее.

Comment: А  std::for_each полезен только, если в функциональном обьекте хранится информация, которая  может быть использована  в дальнейшем, или для вызова методов обьктов контейнера